# Cell broad cast messages command not working in SIM 800C

Tags: at-commands

I am using SIMCom 800C module to get the location through cell broadcast messages. When I am executing command  `AT+CSCB=0,\"50\",\"0-9"` , I get the response 'invalid input value'.
If I put in this format as provided over Internet 
`AT+CSCB=0,"50","0-9"` I get the response  `+CMS ERROR: unknown<CR><LF>`
This is the whole format in which I executed the commands:

```
AT+CMGF=1
AT+CNMI=2,0,2,0,0
AT+CSCB=1
AT+CSCB=0,"50","0-9"
```

Please provide me a solution to this problem.

Comment: Please link to the datasheet for this device. Also, confirm if any commands are interpreted without error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table with command description from **SIM800 Series_AT Command Manual_V1.09**, that you can get just by register on manufacturer's site, is placed bellow. Of course, all very confusing: *total 5 different `<dcss>` can be supported* but `AT+CSCB?` show 21 selected `<dcss>` at a time by default. In practice I could not change `<dcss>` list but `<mids>` list easy to change by commands described in last row of table.

As I understand default list of `<dcss> = "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,32,33,34,35,36,15"` is enought for you purposes. **So you can change only list of `<mids>` with command `AT+CSCB=0,"50"`.**

[image: manual part1]
[image: manual part2]
[image: manual part3]

**EDIT:**

This is example of successful configure:

[image: SIM800C at-commands exchange screenshot]

Comment: please find below the link for the attempts that i make but still unsuccessful. https://goo.gl/photos/vCXoj3q41aGV12C99 . please do suggest  what can be the reason for this. my main motive is to fetch the location from cell broadcast messages.

Comment: just use `AT+CSCB=0,"50"` without `<dcss>` field. Result of configure you can check with `AT+CSCB?` it will response by default `+CSCB=0,"","0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,32,33,34,35,36,15"` and after configure `+CSCB=0,"50","0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,32,33,34,35,36,15"`. As I understand it's well enough.

Comment: @pranjalkhanduri, I have add example of command use, with results of configure.

Comment: sir i followed the steps that u provide but still error is coming,but when i changed my sim card (another service provider) its automatically gives me the location message. https://goo.gl/photos/2msoe8K2P7fSM5Bx5 .kindly help me out in figuring the values that i have to feed manually to get this message manually. https://goo.gl/photos/uZsYodReHUz8Ss8s6

Comment: @pranjalkhanduri, you have deservedly get down vote to your question! 

This IS RESPONSE:
 `+CSCB=0,"","0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,32,33,34,35,36,15"` 

**Use only this command:**
**`AT+CSCB=0,"50"`**

Comment: @pranjalkhanduri, and moreover: provider may not transmit location messages. Is not it?

Comment: sir i have configured it as u said but problem was with my service provider instead of sending nearest tower name it was sending other promotional broadcast messages .when i checked with other two different service provider m able to retrieve nearest tower name. that's what i want to achieve .thank you for your valuable help.